# React.js useReducer hook - No overload matches this call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-reducer

I have a counter like this :

```
import { useReducer } from 'react';

type CounterState = {
  count: number;
};

type UpdateAction = {
  type: 'increment' | 'decrement';
  payload: number;
};

type ResetAction = {
  type: 'reset';
};

type CounterAction = UpdateAction | ResetAction;

const initialState = { counter: 0 };

function reducer(state: CounterState, action: CounterAction) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'increment':
      return { count: state.count + action.payload };      
    case 'decrement':
      return { count: state.count - action.payload };
    case 'reset':
      return initialState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export const Counter = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return(
    <>
      Count: {state.count}
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'increment', payload: 10 })}>
        Increment 10
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'decrement', payload: 10 })}>
        Decrement 10
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'reset' })}>Reset</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

If I hover on `useReducer(reducer, initialState)`, it says :

"No overload matches this call.

Overload 1 of 5, '(reducer: ReducerWithoutAction, initializerArg: any, initializer?: undefined): [any, DispatchWithoutAction]', gave the following error.
Argument of type '(state: CounterState, action: CounterAction) => { counter: number; } | CounterState' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReducerWithoutAction'.
Overload 2 of 5, '(reducer: (state: CounterState, action: CounterAction) => { counter: number; } | CounterState, initialState: never, initializer?: undefined): [...]', gave the following error.

Argument of type '{ counter: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'"

In addition, hovering on `dispatch({ type: 'increment', payload: 10 })`, it says :

`Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.`

What is the reason for this? I thought passed arguments were correct.

Comment: You are returning `count` in the reducer, but defining `counter` in the `initialStore`. Update it so that the names match, so: `const initialState = { count: 0 }`

Comment: Thanks a lot to all answers and comments, also I would like to apologize for the typo...
I will be more careful, cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to rename your initial state from **counter** to **count** as follow:

```
const initialState = { count: 0 };
```